# Loading images uploaded with a form not showing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, image, p5.js

The user uploads images with a form. The images should all be displayed in the canvas. Only one of multiple images shows. Maybe the images are not properly loaded?

html:

```js
let value = 0;
var images = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(320, 270);
    
    background(0);
 
 
  const form = document.querySelector('form');

  frameRate(2);
  
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
      var files = form.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
      

      if (files[0]) {
        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
          var reader  = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function () {
            //preview.src = reader.result;
            images[i] = loadImage(reader.result);
            console.log('new image added')
            console.log(images[i]);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]); //reads the data as a URL
          
        }
      }
  });
  
  
  }

  
  let cursor = 0;
  
function draw() {
    background(0);
    if(images.length > 0){ image(images[cursor], 0, 0, width, height - 20); }

    cursor ++;
    if(cursor >= images.length){ cursor = 0}

    fill(255);
    textSize(16);
    text(value, 10, height - 10);

    console.log(cursor);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title>image_classification</title>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.1.1/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="sketch.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Welcome to the site!</h1>

    <form id="imgs" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        images:
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
    </form>

    <br/>

</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea where the problem even lays. Is it me inserting the images into the array incorrectly, or am I doing something wrong with the asynchronous nature of JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by JavaScript scoping.

Take a look at this part of your code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
  var reader  = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    images[i] = loadImage(reader.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
}
```

Because you're using the `var` keyword, your `reader` is actually in **function scope**. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global. If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.

This is why your `reader` variable only appears to work for one of your images.

The simplest fix to this is to use `const` instead of `var` here:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
```

The `const` keyword creates variables in **block scope** which is probably what you expected `var` to do in the first place.

Comment: That's a very good answer! Since const is supported by most browsers now, I'll remove my response

Comment: @nosnahoj-trap Thanks! Your answer isn't wrong, although I would probably use a named function to make it more clear to novices what's going on. Good opportunity to expand on function scope, imho.

Comment: Thanks a million times. I would have never figured this out on myself. And i learned something more about JavaScript.